# Телефонная книга на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу телефонную книгу и столкнулся с проблемой. Метод find_member постоянно возвращает None, независимо есть ли контакт с такой фамилией в файле или нет. В чем может быть проблема? Так же хочу чтобы метод add_member принимал значение find_member для логического оператора if. Прошу помощи.
   **Update 26.05: Данный код уже с правками от AivanF. от 25.05.2019**
   Новый вопрос. Написанный мной метод delete_member подразумевает считывание данных из файла, занесение их в список, а затем обратную запись удалением необходимого контакта. В моем случае, если в файле каретка стоит на последней строке он просто копирует контакты и их становится в два раза больше. Если каретка стоит в пустой строке выдает ошибку пытаясь распарсить строку в методе **init**. Не могу понят в какой направлении копать.
Вот сам код:

```py
class Member:
    def __init__(self, last_name=None, name=None, phone_number=None, from_line=None):
        if from_line is None:
            self.last_name = last_name
            self.name = name
            self.phone_number = phone_number
        else:
            self.last_name, self.name, self.phone_number = str(from_line).replace(" ", '').split("|")

    def input_characters(self):
        self.last_name = input("Введите фамилию: ").capitalize()
        self.name = input("Введите имя: ").capitalize()
        self.phone_number = input("Введите номер телефона: ").capitalize()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0:10} | {1:10} | {2}'.format(self.last_name, self.name, self.phone_number) + '\n'


class Contacts:
    def find_member(self, query):
        with open('data.txt') as file:
            for line in file:
                member = Member(from_line=line)
                if (member.last_name, member.name) == query:
                    return member

    def add_member(self):
        m = Member()
        m.input_characters()
        if c.find_member(query=(m.last_name, m.name)) is None:
            f = open('data.txt', 'a')
            f.write('{0:10} | {1:10} | {2}'.format(m.last_name, m.name, m.phone_number) + '\n')
            print('\nКонтакт {lastName} {name} успешно добавлен\n'.format(lastName=m.last_name, name=m.name))
            f.close()
        else:
            print('Такой контакт уже есть')

    def delete_member(self, query):
        objects = []
        f = open('data.txt', 'r+')
        for line in f.readlines():
            member = Member(from_line=line)
            objects.append(member)
        for object in objects:
            if (member.last_name, member.name) != query:
                f.write(object.__str__())


    def show_all_contacts(self):
        with open('data.txt') as file:
            for line in file:
                member = Member(from_line=line)
                print(member)


def choice():
    selector = None
    try:
        selector = int(input('Введите "1" если хотите найти контакт\n' + \
                             'Введите "2" если хотите добавить новый контакт\n' + \
                             'Введите "3" если хотите удалить контакт\n' + \
                             'Введите "4" если хотите просмотреть всю адресную книгу\n' + \
                             'Ввести здесь ------->:'))
    except ValueError:
        print('\n\nНе корректный ввод!!!\n')
        print('Необходимо ввести целое число!!!\n\n')
    return selector


c = Contacts()
while True:
    selector = choice()
    if selector == 1:
        query = ((input('Для поиска контакта введите его фамилию: ').capitalize(),
                  input('Для поиска контакта введите его имя: ').capitalize()))
        print(c.find_member(query))
    elif selector == 2:
        c.add_member()
    elif selector == 3:
        query = ((input('Для удаления контакта введите его фамилию: ').capitalize(),
                  input('Для удаления контакта введите его имя: ').capitalize()))
        c.delete_member(query)
    elif selector == 4:
        c.show_all_contacts()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте к классу `Member` такой полезный метод:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return 'Member("{}", "{}", "{}")'.format(self.last_name, self.name, self.phone_number)
```

Затем простейший дебаг:

```py
class Contacts:
    def find_member(self, query=None):
        with open('data.txt') as file:
            for line in file:
                member = Member(from_line=line)
                print(member)
                if member.last_name == query:
                    return member
```

Вы получите такой вывод:

```
Member("Last_name       ", "Name      ", "3141592
")
```

То есть, метод `__init__` класса `Member` неправильно распарсил данную ему строку, оставил табы и перенос строки.

Решения:

**Вариант 1.** Убирайте эти лишние символы, например, методом [`str.strip()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-strip-2/)

**Вариант 2.** Используйте готовый функционал для сохранения файлов, например, модуль [**csv**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

**Вариант 3.** Используйте БД, например, встроенный [**SQLite**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Могу еще помощи попросить?.

Comment: @mamba9999 задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Метод delete_member. По моему мнению он должен считывать файл и класть объекты клаcса Member в список, затем вытаскивать из этого списка и если объект не равен query = ('Фамилия', 'Имя'), то записывать обратно в файл.

Comment: Новый топик с этим же кодом?

Comment: @mamba9999 в разработке программ часто бывает масса возможных вариантов, этот вполне рабочий. Но лучше хранить все данные в оперативной памяти, загружать по запуске программы и сохранять по завершению — чтобы не нагружать диск лишний раз. А ещё лучше использовать БД.

Comment: Просто сначала хочу научиться взаимодействовать с файлами. Вот сам кусок кода.

Comment: Видимо форматировать его тут нельзя

Comment: Сделал правку вопроса, если есть возможность. Прошу помочь.